# Dataflow Sideinputs - Worker Cache Size in SDK 2.x

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I am experiencing performance issues in my pipeline in a DoFn that uses large side input of ~ 1GB. The side input is passed using the pvalue.AsList(), which forces materialization of the side input.

The execution graph of the pipeline shows that the particular step spends most of the time for reading the side input. The total amount of data read exceeds the size of the side input by far. Consequently, I conclude that the side input does not fit into memory / cache of the workers even though their RAM is sufficient (using n1-highmem4 workers with 26 GB RAM).

How do I know how big this cache actually is? Is there a way to control its size using Beam Python SDK 2.15.0 (like there was the pipeline option --workerCacheMb=200 for Java 1.x SDK)?

There is no easy way of shrinking my side input more than 10%.

Comment: Is this a streaming pipeline?

Comment: It's a batch pipeline.

Comment: AFAIK the default worker cache size is 100MB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AsList`, you are correct that the whole side input should be loaded into memory. It may be that your worker has enough memory available, but it just takes very long to read 1GB of data into the list. Also, the size of the data that is read depends on the encoding of it. If you can share more details about your algorithm, we can try to figure out how to write a pipeline that may run more efficiently.

---

Another option may be to have an external service to keep your side input - for instance, a Redis instance that you write to on one side, and red from on the other side.

Comment: I was able to resolve the performance issue by shrinking the side input by ~15%. However, I also try to find some general design principles for buidling dataflow pipelines.

Are there any hard limits how big the workers' cache is or does it only depend on how much memory is available?

In which cases one would prefer doing joins using cogroupbykey transformation over ParDos with SideInput? Under which circumstances one would use the Redis instance? When (if at all) is loading the data within the setup() / start_bundle() method of the DoFn a good idea?